# 幾つかの要素がレビューバーの上に重なって表示される

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

レビュー時に表示される固定されたレビューバーがあり、通常はすべての要素がこのレビューバーの下にありますが、幾つかの要素がこれの上に重なって表示されてしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: MSE でも同様のバグ報告がされており、[status-review] になっています。 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344041

Answer (score 4, accepted):

コメントで参照していた MSE での報告をもって [バグが修正](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/345703/edit) されたようです。